# How to clone a Model in mobx?

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, mobx-persist

I have a simple Model with observable id `id`

```
class TodoStore {
  todos = [];
  id: generateId();


  get completedTodosCount() {
    return this.todos.filter(
      todo => todo.completed === true
    ).length;
  }
}

const todoStore = new TodoStore();
```

now I want to add a feature to clone this todo just by duplicate this exact model with new generated `id` with it's todos and any extra infos.

How to do that? `.toJS` and `.createViewModel` doesn't work!